# Not able Uninstall/Update Angular Cli in MAC

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, angular-cli

Not able to uninstall angular cli in mac.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got the issue. The issue is in my .bash_profile file. I commented the following line in bash_profile and it's working fine.

```
alias ng=/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.3.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force.
```

Note: In macOS, you need to add sudo before the npm command. ...

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

for installing

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is fixed. The issue is with my .bash_profile file.